# Manipulating ActionBar from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I would like to know what is recommended way to manipulate with `ActionBar` and `Fragment`.

General navigation in my app is by using `NavigationDrawer`. One fragment however shows music albums and I would like to use Navigation drop down to filter albums by genres. Is it proper way to do that? 
How should I populate genres within `ActionBar's` drop down? Should I do it in `Activity` or in `Fragment`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ActionBar lives in the Activity always, and needs to be controlled/populated from here.

Since you are using fragments, you should use the AB lifecycle methods in the Activity (onCreateOptionsMenu() ) to change the AB items, when you switch between fragments (again this is done in your Activity, so you are already making Fragment changes, and just need to also make AB changes).

I do think you are describing a proper use case for NavDrawer, AB, and Fragment usage - it is appropriate to put filter criteria for your content fragment in the AB.

Comment: OK, so for clarification. Should I do populate filter in Activity or Fragment's onCreateOptionsMenu(). If in fragment, how should I turn off dropdown navigation when exiting from fragment?

Comment: You will need to do it in Activity

Answer (score 1):

You can create a string array in the resources file with the genres listed. This is all inside the resource tag.

```
<string-array name="genres">
<item>music_Genre1</item>
<item>music_Genre2</item>
.....
</string-array>
```

Then add this to the instance of the spinner

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.your_View);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
    R.array.genres, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Or if the array is already made in the onCreateOptionsMenu(), I believe it's there, it should have a string array with the string resources there (@string/dropdown_item), and you can add more there, and, of course, add & change the string name in your resources file. Then use the onItemSelected method to interact with the drop down.

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to populate dropdown navigation. I don't know if I should do it from Fragment or from Activity?

Comment: You should do it in the Activity. That isn't to say you can't in the Fragment, but it's almost always done in the Activity